# What is the purpose of the "landmark" accessibility container type?

Tags: voiceover, uiaccessibility

The [UIAccessibilityContainerType.landmark](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitycontainertype/landmark) enumeration case is described as "Landmark data." This description leaves much to the imagination and I have struggled to find information about this enumeration case elsewhere.

I tried setting the [accessibilityContainerType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/2865802-accessibilitycontainertype) value of some of the views in my app to [landmark](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitycontainertype/landmark) to see whether this changes anything in the VoiceOver experience of my app. I did not see any change. I thought I might see an extra "Landmarks" rotor option if nothing else but this was not the case.

What is the purpose of [UIAccessibilityContainerType.landmark](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitycontainertype/landmark) enumeration case? Does it have any impact on an app's VoiceOver experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if a brilliant answer has already been provided by [@slugolicious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76714/) , I deem it important to bring some information regarding the question in the "iOS world" with the sources.

> What is the purpose of UIAccessibilityContainerType.landmark enumeration case? Does it have any impact on an app's VoiceOver experience?

I asked myself the same questions and wrote a TSI (n°1631349) to Apple who answered: "the **landmarks** are the same as in HTML and are **for web content & tvOS**".

It's definitely **not designed for iOS**. In the [Accessibility design for Mac Catalyst](https://Accessibility%20design%20for%20Mac%20Catalyst) WWDC 2020 video, it is highlighted in the [What are accessibility containers?](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10117/?time=774) section.

[image: Screenshot of the "Accessibility design for Mac Catalyst" WWDC 2020 video]

I'm used to watching the [WWDC summaries](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/nota11y/) written by [Orange Digital Accessibility](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/)  but this video isn't present.

Moreover, this assertion is also outlined by the [Apple support team](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204783):
[image]

Finally, **don't use this container type in an iOS app** for which the [semanticGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitycontainertype/semanticgroup) is definitely more appropriate and understood by VoiceOver regarding this OS.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you're programming for iOS, the [definition of a landmark](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#landmark) for HTML might help you understand the concept.

In HTML, you don't use the landmark role directly.  It's an abstract class.  You use one of the subclasses as show in the table in the aforementioned link.

For iOS, since the enum for `UIAccessibilityContainerType.landmark` is just one value, it sounds like iOS doesn't have multiple types of landmarks but just one generic landmark.

Having said that, you might not see Landmarks in your Voiceover rotor unless you enable them for the rotor.  Go into Settings > Accessibility > Voiceover > Rotor and scroll down until you see "Landmarks" and make sure it's checked.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Then you should see "Landmarks" in your rotor.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: I turned on the "Landmarks" option in the Settings > Accessibility > Voiceover > Rotor screen after reading your answer and I'm still not seeing "Landmarks" appear in the Rotor for any apps on any of my iPhone devices. I also tried setting the [accessibilityContainerType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/2865802-accessibilitycontainertype) value of some of the views in my app to [landmark](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitycontainertype/landmark) after adding "Landmarks" to my device's "Rotor" options but that had no effect either.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted because it's clear that that is how it is supposed to behave. As for my apps, I'm going to stick to setting the [accessibilityContainerType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/2865802-accessibilitycontainertype) value of my views to [semanticGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitycontainertype/semanticgroup) because it seems to afford me a more reliable and deterministic outcome (i.e. the views marked as such appear to VoiceOver as "Containers"). Thanks for your help 