# How group a UITableView for VoiceOver?

Tags: swift, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

I have a UITableView with infinite cells, these are loaded as you scroll down. And I also have a floating button at the bottom. VoiceOver reads the cells one by one, the problem is that as new cells are loaded, the button is never reached. I would like VoiceOver to treat the table as a group, to access and go through its elements and to be able to exit to go to the button. What I want is something similar to what
[the mail app currently does](https://mega.nz/file/10Bl0LTb#ZRcFJou-E5HvQtEV1RcnMO_iQIwqQoOj6MM7coE4uro).

I'm working with UIKit in Swift.

I've tried setting the `UITableView` with the `isAccessibilityElement` flag to `true` but it doesn't seem to affect anything.  I have also tried with the `accessibilityContainerType` setting it to `.semanticGroup`.

The `accessibilityLabel` to the `UITableView` does read it when it enters the first cell.

Answer (score 2):

You followed the appropriate path by using the `accessibilityContainerType` property with the [.semanticGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75609772/3825084) value but I think you wrote it only for the table view. 
To move from one group to another, this property should be inserted to each of the desired elements.

I reproduced your environment under **Xcode 14** and **iOS 16.4** using `UIKit` and the storyboard.
[image]

I implemented this property to the label, the table view and the button so as to make VoiceOver understand that three different groups of elements may be selected:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
    let maxCells = 100

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        myLabel.accessibilityContainerType = .semanticGroup
        myTableView.accessibilityContainerType = .semanticGroup
        myButton.accessibilityContainerType = .semanticGroup
    
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
        myTableView.headerView(forSection: 0)?.accessibilityFrame = myTableView.frame
        myTableView.headerView(forSection: 0)?.accessibilityLabel = "HERE IS THE TABLE VIEW"
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return maxCells }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? { return "THE TABLE VIEW TITLE" }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        let myCell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell",
                                                     for: indexPath)
        var config = myCell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        config.text = "Table view cell n° \(indexPath.row)"
    
        myCell.contentConfiguration = config
        return myCell
    }
}
```

Next, follow the steps below to understand the [proper gestures](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/voiceover/) for reaching your goal with VoiceOver:

1. Through the rotor, **select the `Containers` item**.
2. From the label, **flick down using one finger** to reach the first element in the table view.
3. From this location, reproduce this gesture to get out of the table view and find the button.
   [image]
4. When inside the table view, it's still possible to **scroll** for getting each cells by **swiping left/right with one finger**.
5. Wherever the location in the table view, you can **reach the button** just by **flicking down using one finger**.
   [image]

You can now consider your table view as a group and get out of it without scrolling all the cells inside with VoiceOver.

⚠️ **EDIT 2023/09/04** ⚠️

I've finally understood the way you got this use case. 
To get this specific behavior, you use the **Navigation Style** mode available in the settings *(through the rotor as well)* since iOS 15:
[image]

When developing, this `API` is **only available for the `Switch Control`** and can be [embedded in an app](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#switch-control) this way but it's **impossible with `VoiceOver`** for which Apple uses [this property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615200-accessibilitynavigationstyle) as private.

> Switch Control uses this technology, but VoiceOver and other assistive
> technologies do not.

Moreover, there's [no notification](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#accessibility-options) to be aware of the `Navigation Style` mode.

Finally, if you want to reach a behavior like the native mail app with VoiceOver in iOS 16 with `UIKit`, **the only way is to use the containers** as described in my initial answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Indeed, this is the alternative that is closest to the behavior of the native mail application, in fact it is the one that I applied. However, it is not exactly the same as what mail does, since in mail the entire table is an accessible element, with an accessbilityLabel, it is completely marked and with the gesture of two fingers to the right the group is accessed.

Comment: @JeronimoCabezueloRuiz I understood your problem only dealt with the table view exit fo reaching the button whatever the cell. 
I fixed my first answer by adding a title with a dedicated accessibility label that's read out when you select the table view that's now defined as a whole group thanks to the dedicated accessibility frame of the title.
That should work as desired... it's up to you to customize as you wish. 

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the response. My problem is solved with the `myButton.accessibilityContainerType = .semanticGroup` since the button can be reached using the containers. However, that is not what the email application does. In mail, the table is a group and you can enter and leave it. The modification you have made simply places the table as another element, also making the first header unable to have an accessible label. What I am asking with this question is if it is possible to group the elements of the table as native applications do, for example, mail.

Comment: I think to answer your initial goal with my answer ‍, sorry for wasting your time and glad to hear you solved your problem for getting out the table view to reach the button... you could have brought your solution marked as accepted here to inform others how you did it. 

Comment: Don't worry, there is no waste of time. It is true that I should have explained that I did achieve this, but you have explained it much better. Although I have solved my initial problem, I still don't know how to do what native apps like mail do.

Comment: @JeronimoCabezueloRuiz I think I've understood the way you got this behavior... the gesture with" two fingers to the right" mentioned in your first comment arose my curiosity. See my edit for the explanations. 